# C++ environmental variable

Tags: c++, types, environment-variables

What I am trying to do is to get environmental variable value and use it in code itself.

What I am trying to do is (with variable set as `export UTMZONE="33T"`):

```
char UTMZone[4] = getenv("UTMZONE");
```

With that I receive following error:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

I presume issue is with mixing types, but I have no idea what kind of conversion do I have to make.

Comment: arrays cannot be assigned as a whole. Use `std::string` for character arrays

Comment: If you're not opposed I'd suggest `std::string UTMZone = std::getenv("UTMZONE");` instead, otherwise you'll need to `strcpy` or similar

Comment: (To the commenters: if you have a valid answer, put it as an answer below, so Bostja can accept it)

Comment: Hello All, thank you for very prompt responses. @CoryKramer, problem is that I am using this in future functions and I need `const char*`, as I receive following error when compiling: `error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘4’ to ‘void UTMtoLL(int, double, double, const char*, double&, double&)’`. For `strcpy`, would I have to set it like `cost char* env = getenv("UTMZONE"); char UTMZone[4]; strcpy(UTMZone, env)`? As I tried it and did not work either.

Comment: If you need a `const char*` later you can just say `UTMZone.c_str()` as needed

Comment: @Bostjan: Then you'd use `UTMZone.c_str()` to extract a `const char*` pointer to the data buffer. Note though that the pointer is only valid for as long as the `std::string` is in scope and not modified.

Comment: May I suggest you to check the length of the env var before deciding that a vector of 4 char is enough? (I'm implying that you should consider an allocation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getenv` returns a `char*`.  There isn't a way to initialize a `char[N]` from a `char*`.  What you would need to do is capture the pointer and then copy the string to the array like

```
char UTMZone[4];
char* ret = getenv("UTMZONE");
if (ret)
    strncpy(UTMZone, ret, 4);
else
    // abort
```

That said, if you can use a `std::string`, that is constructable from a `char*`.  Using

```
char* ret = getenv("UTMZONE");
if (ret)
    std::string UTMZone = ret;
else
    // abort
```

gives you a string populated with the environment variable.  If you need to pass it to a something that needs a `char*` or `const char*` then you can use the `data()` or `c_str()` member functions respectively. That would look like

```
function_that_needs_char_star(UTMZone.data());
function_that_needs_const_char_star(UTMZone.c_str());
```

Comment: `std::string UTMZone = getenv("UTMZONE");` is problematic if the environment variable does not exist, as getenv will return NULL.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for response and explanation. Both options that you mentioned resolved the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that your subsequent code will most likely have undefined behaviour if the environment variable is at least four characters long.

Comment: @KerrekSB Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use a char array and know for sure that you only need the first three chars of UTMZONE you could use this:

```
char* envptr = std::getenv("UTMZONE");
if(envptr){ // check the pointer isn't null
  char UTMZone[4];

  // set null terminator
  UTMZone[4] = '\0';

  // copy 3 chars as the null terminator is already there
  std::strncpy(UTMZone, 3, envptr);
}
```

you should really use strings instead of char[] though as those are much safer.

edit: Nathan was both quicker and more eloquent :(

edit: adjusted for use of strncpy instead of strcpy and added NULL check

Comment: `strncpy` would be far safer, and the return value could be checked too.

Comment: not sure what `strcpy` would do if you pass a null-pointer as second parameter in case the env var was not found (maybe thats what Bathsheba is already refering to)

Comment: `UTMZone[4] = '\0'`: No!!! this is a buffer overflow (and it's missing semicolon BTW)

Comment: Thanks I missed the semicolon. Can you explain how exactly this is a buffer overflow? I reserved space for four characters and now I fill the fourth with a null terminator so I don't see the problem.